# Creating promise for authorizing http requests on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a `javascript`/`nodejs` function which should be a promise and returns a successful callback if it validates a user else sends the `403` unauthorized response. The reason to make it async is it needs to call my database to validate the api key for the user.

I am aware of a express middleware but I am not able to use it because of some reason. So I am trying to convert that to the async promise function which validates the request and then executes the request.

My express middleware function currently look like this. Which I am converting to a promise function:

```
const validateApiKey = (req, res, next) => {

        console.log('Check if request is authorized with API Key');

        if (!req.headers.authorization) {
            res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
            return;
        }
        const apiKey = req.headers.authorization.split('Key=')[1];
        console.log('api key: ' + apiKey);

        if (apiKeyUserMap[apiKey] != null) {
            admin.database().ref('apiKeyMapping/' + apiKey).once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
                console.log('user: ' + dataSnapshot.val());
                req.uid = dataSnapshot.val();
                next();
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Error while getting uid from API key');
            res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        }
    });
};
```

As, I am using firebase function, the function would look something like this:

```
exports.helloUser= functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return validateApiKey(req, res).then((req,res) => {
    // do whatever you like
    });
});
```

Now, I am getting confused how to handle that `res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')` part. This validation will be there on all of my functions.

So how to send `403` response. Like, if I send from the Promise function, will the `then()` function  or `catch()` function be called? Or do I need to handle all `403` inside all of my firebase functions instead of inside `validateApiKey` function?

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what's going on here.  It looks like the second bit of code is expecting `validateApiKey` to return a promise, but as far as I can tell, it never actually does that.  Also, it is expecting a function parameter called `next`, but that's never being passed.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for looking into it. That function is currently as express middleware. (As shown in firebase functions authenticated-https-endpoints) Which I am trying to convert to with promise. So that I can make database async call and then continue what user has requested.